# Error Unauthorized 401 when trying to upload a file to SharePoint 365

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Does anyone know if the following code is supported by SharePoint 365:

```
try
{
    context.ClientContext.RequestTimeout = timeoutSeconds * 1000;

    using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(sourceFilePath))
    {
        File.SaveBinaryDirect(context.ClientContext, serverRelativeUrl, fileStream, overwrite);
    }
}
```

As I'm getting an error 401 (Unauthorized) when I'm trying to upload it to SharePoint 365 but this work in various clients when they are using a local copy of SharePoint.

Note that I can upload a file and metadata just fine using CSOM but I'm curious about this specific code as it definitely works when used locally.

I assume, and again, it could be the wrong assumption, that since I can upload via CSOM, that I have the relevant permissions in SharePoint 365.

Also, it is returning me a SharePoint context and to verify that my code was right, I switch the TenantId and ClientId and it returns an error which when I swapped it back, the error disappeared and my code continue to execute which would indicate to me that my app is successfully registered in Azure under the App Registration.

Using that context and some CSOM, I was able to get the title using the sharePointContext which I assume is another positive indication that my context is definitely ok but why am I getting permission errors (401) using this code which is used to upload a file.

Note that I'm getting the same error when trying to download a file using:

```
try
{
    context.RequestTimeout = timeoutSeconds * 1000;

    var fileInformation = File.OpenBinaryDirect(context.ClientContext, serverRelativeUrl);
    using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(targetFilePath))
        fileInformation.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
}
```

Thanks.